# How to translate date object - Angular 9, TypeScript, HTML

Tags: html, typescript, date, angular9, translate

There is part of code (HTML):

```
<span class="small"> {{ today | date:'EEEE' }} </span>
```

I would like to translate name of the days. In my project I translate in this way:

```
<span> {{ 'application.title' |translate }}</span>
```

I have folder i18n and there are two json files for two languages. But I don't know if I can translate date object in this way. I'm looking for a very simple solution.

I'm using Angular 9, TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the translate pipe work you have to configure previously the TranslateModule.

First of all, if you haven't done it yet,

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core
```

and to use the default loader

```
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

Then you have to import the TranslateModule in your module,

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
})
```

Finally, inject in your desired component TranslateService to initialize the default language.

```
translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
```

If you have done all those steps and the translations created in the json files match the string in the pipe you should be good to go.